# Discolored wall/ceiling I think from condensation. How do I prevent it further?

Tags: insulation, ceiling, condensation

Area near ceiling/wall is discolored a little dark, kinda like it's dirty/dusty. Only in master bedroom. There is no door between bed and master bath. I think it's from my wife's long showers having a little condensation there. It isn't wet when it's raining out but damp after the shower. I borrowed a Flir camera from work and the top edge of the wall was significantly colder than everywhere else on the floor. My best guess is the insulation on the wall or doesn't fill the top couple inches, it's colder there, and the moisture humidity condenses only there. Over the years it discolored. Seen like a reasonable hypothesis?  Any easy way to test it or fix it?

Comment: Dust/dirt collecting there from condensation should clean off easy.  A stain from a leak above should not clean easy.  Can google ceiling shadows or ghosting.

Comment: It would be easier to comment with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

improve the bathroom ventilation, or install a door.